# No SSML audio tag is rendered in Google Assistant main invocation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I have the following invocation:

```
candidates:
  - first_simple:
      variants:
        - speech: >-
            <speak><audio
            url="https://example.com/welcome.mp3"></audio></speak>
          text: Welcome to my App!
    suggestions:
      - title: Explore
      - title: Guess
```

When I test it I do not hear mp3 being played, only see welcome text.

What I do incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using SSML is only possible in a webhook. Returning `speech` from a webhook resolved the issue.